# For a quadrilateral with a circumcircle and an incircle, find the area from two sides and a diagonal.

Tags: geometry, circles

The following figure is given with the lengths of the sides and the diagonal:

[image]

> We can circumscribe a circle around the quadrilateral and inscribe a circle in it. How can the area of the quadrilateral be found?

I do not understand what to do with these circles. How are they helping me?

Comment: Cyclic quadrilaterals have certain properties; inscriptable quadrilaterals have certain properties. These "bi-centric" quadrilaterals have both. See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicentric_quadrilateral) for an overview.

Comment: Have you noticed that angle $B=120$ degrees?

Comment: I was not. Why is it 120?

Comment: Use the Law of Cosines: $\left(10\sqrt{7}\right)^2=20^2+10^2-2(20)(10)\cos  B$

Answer (score 2):

From the law of cosines:

$$AC^2=AB^2+BC^2-2AB\cdot BC \cos \angle B$$

$$(10\sqrt7)^2=10^2+20^2-2\cdot10\cdot20\cos\angle B$$

$$700=100+400-400\cos\angle B$$

$$\cos\angle B=-\frac12$$

$$\angle B=120^\circ$$

The fact that you can draw a circumscribed circle means that quadrilateral $ABCD$ is cyclic. In a cyclic quadrilateral the sum of the opposite angles is $180^\circ$. So we have:

$$\angle D=180^\circ-\angle B=60^\circ$$

The fact that you can inscribe the circle in a quadruilateral means that the sum of opposite sides must be equal. Therefore:

$$AB+CD=BC+DA$$

$$10+CD=20+DA$$

Introduce $CD=x$. It means that $DA=x-10$. Now apply cosine theorem to triangle ACD:

$$CD^2+DA^2-2CD\cdot DA\cos\angle D=AC^2$$

$$x^2+(x-10)^2-2x(x-10)\cos60^\circ=(10\sqrt7)^2$$

$$x^2+(x-10)^2-x(x-10)=700$$

$$x^2-10x-600=0$$

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{10\pm\sqrt{10^2+4\cdot 600}}{2}=\frac{10\pm50}{2}$$

If you discard negative solution, you get:

$$x=CD=30$$

$$DA=x-10=20$$

Finding the area is simple:

$$A_{ABC}=\frac12 AB\cdot BC\sin\angle B=\frac12 10\cdot20\sin120^\circ=50\sqrt 3$$
$$A_{ACD}=\frac12 CD\cdot DA\sin\angle D=\frac12 30\cdot20\sin60^\circ=150\sqrt 3$$

...so the total area is:

$$A=A_{ABC}+A_{ACD}=200\sqrt3$$

Comment: Not see you long time +1

Comment: @Aqua Health issues :(

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Hope you are better now!

Comment: area triangle $ABC=50 \sqrt 3$ and area triangle $ACD=150 \sqrt 3$

Comment: Yeah the answer is $200 \sqrt 3$, but thank you for the solution :)

Comment: @Lozenges Forgot 1/2, corrected that. thanks.

Comment: @MaximKasnedelchev Stupid mistake corrected.

Comment: @Aqua Thanks Aqua, I’m much better now.